# Generic type java.util.List inheritance

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance

Lets say I've got two classes **Person** and **Child**. **Child** inherits from **Person**. I have also 2 other classes **Class1** and **Class2**.

**Class1** has constructor with only one parameter - its a java.util.**List** of **Person**.
**Class2** has List of **Child**. I want to pass these childs to **Class1** constructor. But I can't do it - Eclipse says that

```
The constructor Class1(List<Child>) is undefined.
```

I thought it would be possible because **Child** inherits from **Person**. What is the problem?

SSCCE (not compilable) may looks like this:

Somewhere in Class2

```
List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
new Class1(childs);
```

Class1 constructor

```
public Class1(List<Person> persons)
{
//do nothing();
}
```

Comment: List<Child> is not a sub class of List<Person>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `List<Apple>` was a `List<Fruit>`, you could do the following:

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
List<Fruit> fruits = apples; // this doesn't actually compile
fruits.add(new Banana());
```

And it would thus completely break the type-safety of generic types. If you want Class1 to accept a list of any type of Person, it should take a `List<? extends Person>` as argument.

Comment: better answer because there is an explanation why this is impossible

Answer (score 2):

If you define a constructor this way

```
public Class1(List<? extends Person> persons) {
}
```

you will be able to pass `List<Child>` to  it